# illegal line end in character literal

Tags: java, switch-statement

****About the code: I am just making a simple code using a switch statement. All the switch cases work fine except the double-digit cases. I get an error saying :**

`year.java:37: error: unclosed character literal`
`case '10'`
`year.java:40: error: unclosed character literal`
`case '11':year.java:43: error: unclosed character literal`
`case '12'`

**Code :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class year {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char year;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of the month ");
        year = input.next().charAt(0);
        switch(year){
            case '1': 
            System.out.println("January");
            break;
            case '2':
            System.out.println("Febraury");
            break;
            case '3':
            System.out.println("March");
            break;
            case '4':
            System.out.println("April");
            break;
            case '5':
            System.out.println("May");
            break;
            case '6':
            System.out.println("June ");
            break;
            case '7':
            System.out.println("July");
            break;
            case '8':
            System.out.println("August ");
            break;
            case '9':
            System.out.println("September ");
            break;
            case '10':
            System.out.println("October");
            break;
            case '11':
            System.out.println("November");
            break;
            case '12'
            System.out.println("December");
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid");

        }
        input.close();

    }
}
```

I tried doing a few changes here and there but couldn't understand them and thus could not do so.

Comment: So when I input 10 for October, then you think the first char is "10" and not "1"? Why? You don't want to work with char, convert the input to `int` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `year` is a char. A char can only be a single character.

Therefore when you try and do `'11'` or `'12'` you run into issues as these "chars" consist of more than one character.

The quick solution here would be to use a String instead of char, using `input.next()` without the `.charAt(0)`. Then you would need to change your case statements to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Alternatively, you could do `Integer.parseInt(input.next())` and then switch on an int instead, as @Tom has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a Syntax error in `case '12'` it should be `case '12':`
(Also the code indention is bad. Poor indentation make it hard for debugging)

I suggest you convert this code to a `String` based one. Please check the complete example below.
Char can get one character only and `char year;` cause a bug, because in input values like 10, 11, 12 it won't work as expected

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class year {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String year;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of the month ");
        year = input.nextLine();
        switch(year){
            case "1": 
            System.out.println("January");
            break;
            case "2":
            System.out.println("Febraury");
            break;
            case "3":
            System.out.println("March");
            break;
            case "4":
            System.out.println("April");
            break;
            case "5":
            System.out.println("May");
            break;
            case "6":
            System.out.println("June ");
            break;
            case "7":
            System.out.println("July");
            break;
            case "8":
            System.out.println("August ");
            break;
            case "9":
            System.out.println("September ");
            break;
            case "10":
            System.out.println("October");
            break;
            case "11":
            System.out.println("November");
            break;
            case "12":
            System.out.println("December");
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid");

        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```